# My Mouse Handler Class results in a geometric progression between the mouse movement and the result, I am looking for why

Tags: java, event-handling

/*  This code is working and allows different shapes to be drawn in an
applet. The only problem is when you try to move or resize the motion of
the mouse is exaggerated by a geometric progression i.e. the further you
try to move the object the worse the exaggeration.

does anyone know what would cause this?
*/

```
package event;


import interfaces.ComparableShapes;

import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Vector;

import model.ModelOne;
// import model.ModelOne.ActionEnum;
import shapes.*;
// import ui.applet.*;
// import java.awt.Graphics;

public class ShapeMouseHandler extends MouseAdapter 
{
    private ModelOne ntcModel;
    // Need Variables for the upper left corner of a shape
    private int upLtX;
    private int upLtY;
    // Create variables for the move operation
    private int moveStartX;
    private int moveStartY;
    // These were added in version 2 rewrite to replace SelectPoint objects
    private int resizeStartX;
    private int resizeStartY;

    private int currentClickCount; // This holds polygon x and y array index
    // private int selectedXcoord; // added for remove, move, change functionality
    // private int selectedYcoord; // added for remove, move, change functionality
    private Shape currentShape; // for now I will hold the current shape here

    private boolean dragInProgress; // On when a Drag is in progress


    // All SelectPoints to be decomissioned
    // private SelectPoint currentSelectPoint; // Holds the last point selected by mouse click
    // private SelectPoint currentMoveStart; // Holds the starting point of a move function
    // private SelectPoint currentMoveEnd; // Holds the ending point of a move function

    // Next is the constructor associates a model to the listener
    public ShapeMouseHandler(ModelOne mouseModel)
    {
        // Linking the passed in model to this model
        this.ntcModel = mouseModel;
    }

    // This is the MouseAdapter MousePressed Method - see if mouse is clicked
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mousePressEvent)
    {
        /* I am switching all mouse events to work with the switch statement based on
         *  the selected action that will give me independent functionality control for each
         */
         // Determine which shape is currently selected
         currentShape = ntcModel.getSelectedShape(mousePressEvent.getX(), mousePressEvent.getY());

          switch (ntcModel.getActionEnum())
          {
          case DRAW:  // action = Draw
             // Establish the upper left corner of the current shape
             upLtX = mousePressEvent.getX();
             upLtY = mousePressEvent.getY();
             // Ask the model to create a starter shape
             currentShape = ntcModel.createShape();
             // proceed if a shape has been created - not sure how it would not be  
             if (currentShape != null)
             {
                 // Set upper left coordinates to location of the mouse
                 currentShape.setXorigin(mousePressEvent.getX());
                 currentShape.setYorigin(mousePressEvent.getY());
                 // Now we need to set the Width and Height parameters
                 // If the user does not drag the mouse
                 if (currentShape instanceof Oval)
                 {
                     ((Oval) currentShape).setBoundBoxWidth(50);
                     ((Oval) currentShape).setBoundBoxHeight(50);
                 }
             }
             // Tell the model to repaint the applet or Application
             ntcModel.repaint();
           break; // break for case Action = 0 (Draw)

           case MOVE: // case for case Action = 1 (Move)
              // Establish location of currentShape
              // currentShape = ntcModel.getSelectedShape(mousePressEvent.getX(), mousePressEvent.getY());
              // Establish the start point for the object move
                if(currentShape == null)
                {
                    // Do nothing for now - later add a message to user "Remove What"
                    System.out.println("\nYou have asked to move a shape but there are no shapes drawn");
                }
                else
                {
                  if (dragInProgress == false)
                  {
                     // Establish a baseline for a move operation to be performed in drag event
                     moveStartX = mousePressEvent.getX();
                     moveStartY = mousePressEvent.getY();
                  } // close dragInProgress condition
                }
           break; // break for case Action = 1 (Move)

           case RESIZE: // case for case Action = 2 (Resize)
                // Establish location of currentShape
                // currentShape = ntcModel.getSelectedShape(mousePressEvent.getX(), mousePressEvent.getY());
                // Establish the start point for the object resize
                if(currentShape == null)
                {
                    // Do nothing for now - later add a message to user "Remove What"
                    System.out.println("\nYou have asked to resize a shape but there are no shapes drawn");
                }
                else
                {
                    // Establish a baseline for a resize operation to be performed in drag event
                    resizeStartX = mousePressEvent.getX();
                    resizeStartY = mousePressEvent.getY();
                }
              // currentShape = ntcModel.getSelectedShape(mousePressEvent.getX(), mousePressEvent.getY());

           break; // break for case Action = 2 (Resize)
           case REMOVE: // case for case Action = 3 (Remove)
                ntcModel.removeShapesToCompare(((ComparableShapes)currentShape)); // Added to overcome Concurrent Modification Error
                // tell the applet to redraw the shapes
                ntcModel.repaint();

           break; // break for case Action = 3 (Remove)
           case CHANGE: // case for case Action = 4 (Change)

               // System.out.println("\n***Debug - The Change Option is selected");
               /* There are 4 conditions to address:
                *  1) If there is no shape I cannot change a shape
                *  2) If we are not in Multi Shape mode, I change the only shape present, Will still use mouse to initiate change
                *  3) In Multi shape mode I need to determine what shape is selected by mouse click listener
                *  3a) only one shape identified as selected, change the shape selected
                *  3b) more than one shape selected - for now change them all
                *  The basis of the change functionality is to take the target shape and change it's 
                *  Shape definition: Triangle, Pentagon etc. , line color and fill color based on the UI
                *  Ok so it took a 5 mile run for me to realize I cannot take a class triangle and turn it
                *  into a pentagon. So we need to retrieve the shape data, delete the old shape,
                *  create a new shape and give it the shape data from the last shape.
                */

                // Establish location of currentShape
                // currentShape = ntcModel.getSelectedShape(mousePressEvent.getX(), mousePressEvent.getY());
                if(currentShape == null)
                {
                    // Do nothing for now - later add a message to user "Change What"
                    System.out.println("\nYou have asked to change a shape but there are no shapes drawn");
                }
                else if (currentShape != null)
                {
                       // get the current mouse coordinates
                       // compare current mouse coordinates with shapes in Vector
                    Vector <ComparableShapes> shapeVector = ntcModel.getShapesToCompare();
                    // Get the data for the current shape so it can be used as a baseline for the new shape 
                    int currentXOrigin = ((Shape)(currentShape)).getXorigin();
                    int currentYOrigin = ((Shape)(currentShape)).getYorigin();
                    int currentWidth = ((BoundRectShapes)(currentShape)).getBoundBoxWidth();
                    int currentHeight = ((BoundRectShapes)(currentShape)).getBoundBoxHeight();
                    // Remove the shape being changed
                    shapeVector.remove(currentShape);
                    // Create a new shape where the old shape was just sitting
                    ntcModel.createShape(); 
                    currentShape = ntcModel.getCurrentShape();
                    currentShape.setXorigin(currentXOrigin);
                    currentShape.setYorigin(currentYOrigin);
                    ((BoundRectShapes)(currentShape)).setBoundBoxWidth(currentWidth);
                    ((BoundRectShapes)(currentShape)).setBoundBoxHeight(currentHeight);
                    currentShape.setSelect(true);

                    shapeVector.add((ComparableShapes)(currentShape));

                }// end of if current shape not null
                // tell the applet to redraw the shapes
                ntcModel.repaint();

           break; // break for case Action = 4 (Change)
           default:
           break;

          } // end of switch statement
    }

    // This is the MouseAdapter mouseDragged method - see if mouse is dragged
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent dragEvent)
    {
        /* I am switching all mouse events to work with the switch statement based on
         *  the selected action that will give me independent functionality control for each
         */

          // This is an attempt to fix the grometric drag problem
          dragInProgress = true; // This will allow me to turn off mousePressed while drag in running

          switch (ntcModel.getActionEnum())
          {
          case DRAW:  // action = Draw
              //currentShape = ntcModel.getCurrentShape();
              // proceed if a shape has been created - not sure how it would not be 
              if (currentShape != null)
              {
                  // Check to see if we are in DRAW mode.
                  // if (ntcModel.getAction() == ModelOne.DRAW)
                  if (ntcModel.getActionEnum() == ModelOne.ActionEnum.DRAW)
                  {
                      // Set upper left coordinates to location of the mouse
                      // There is a note in the code about this allowing "rubber-banding"
                      currentShape.setXorigin(Math.min(upLtX, dragEvent.getX()));
                      currentShape.setYorigin(Math.min(upLtY, dragEvent.getY()));
                  }
                  // Now we need to set the Width and Height parameters
                  // If the user does not drag the mouse
                  if (currentShape instanceof Oval)
                  {
                      // Set ending point by mouse drag coordinates
                      // So here we are casting the variable currentShape into a OriginBasedShapes type
                      // object so we can use the OriginBasedShapes setter Methods "setXwidth and setXheight"
                      ((Oval) currentShape).setBoundBoxWidth(Math.abs(upLtX - dragEvent.getX()));
                      ((Oval) currentShape).setBoundBoxHeight(Math.abs(upLtY - dragEvent.getY()));
                  }
                  else if (currentShape instanceof BoundRectShapes)
                  {
                      // Set ending point by mouse drag coordinates
                      // So here we are casting the variable currentShape into a OriginBasedShapes type
                      // object so we can use the OriginBasedShapes setter Methods "setXwidth and setXheight"
                      // ((BoundRectShapes) currentShape).setXwidth(Math.abs(upLtX - dragEvent.getX()));
                      // ((BoundRectShapes) currentShape).setYheight(Math.abs(upLtY - dragEvent.getY()));
                      ((BoundRectShapes) currentShape).setBoundBoxWidth(dragEvent.getX());
                      ((BoundRectShapes) currentShape).setBoundBoxHeight(dragEvent.getY());
                  }
                  if (currentShape instanceof ArrayBasedShapes)
                  {
                      // Set ending point by mouse drag coordinates
                      // So here we are casting the variable currentShape into a ArrayBasedShapes type
                      // object so we can use the ArrayBasedShapes setter Methods "setXnext and setYnext"
                      // The idea here is we are loading a set of array click points one for x values
                      // and the other for y values
                      ((ArrayBasedShapes) currentShape).setXcoords(Math.abs(upLtX - dragEvent.getX()), currentClickCount );
                      ((ArrayBasedShapes) currentShape).setYcoords(Math.abs(upLtY - dragEvent.getY()), currentClickCount );
                  }
              }
              // Tell the model to repaint the applet or application
              ntcModel.repaint();
           break; // break for case Action = 0 (Draw)
           case MOVE: // case for case Action = 1 (Move)
               /* Concept - click the mouse somewhere in a shape and drag it to a new location. I need to
                * Capture the Mouse pressed event when the move box is selected
                * Capture the mouse dragged end location when the move box is selected
                * replace the starting coordinates (xStart and yStart) by adding (or subtracting) the difference
                * between the mousePressed event and the mouseDragged event
                * The solution will require logic that can handle all combinations of 3 x/y positions
                * 1) the Current starting x/y position of the object
                * 2) the Mouse pressed position (which can only be greater than 1) above
                * 3) the mouse dragged to position
                * In addition there are 2 scenarios:
                * 1) No shape present - nothing to move
                * 2) Multi shape mode - deal with shape in a vector
                *  After first attempt it looks like I have to retrieve the width and height and reset them
                *  on a move otherwise the endpoint does not move.
                */
                // System.out.println("\n***Debug - The Move Option is selected");
                if(currentShape == null)
                {
                    // Do nothing for now - later add a message to user "Remove What"
                    System.out.println("\nYou have asked to move a shape but there are no shapes drawn");
                }
                else if (currentShape != null)

                {
                    // Get the starting X and Y position of the selected shape
                    int shapeXPosition = ((Shape)(currentShape)).getXorigin();
                    int shapeYPosition = ((Shape)(currentShape)).getYorigin();
                    // Get the width and height of the current shape so we can reuse it in the new location
                    int shapeWidth = ((BoundRectShapes)(currentShape)).getBoundBoxWidth();
                    int shapeHeight = ((BoundRectShapes)(currentShape)).getBoundBoxHeight();
                    // Get the end point for the move from the drag event
                    int moveEndX = dragEvent.getX();
                    int moveEndY = dragEvent.getY();
                    // Reposition the selected shape based on the difference between the mousePressed
                    // and mouseDragged events
                    ((Shape)(currentShape)).setXorigin(shapeXPosition + (moveEndX - moveStartX)); 
                    ((Shape)(currentShape)).setYorigin(shapeYPosition + (moveEndY - moveStartY)); 
                    System.out.println("*** Debug: StartX, EndX, StartY, EndY "+ moveStartX + " " + moveEndX + " " + moveStartY + " " + moveEndY);
                    // These next 2 lines do not work for the oval
                    if (currentShape instanceof Oval)
                    {
                        ((BoundRectShapes)(currentShape)).setBoundBoxWidth(shapeWidth);
                        ((BoundRectShapes)(currentShape)).setBoundBoxHeight(shapeHeight);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ((BoundRectShapes)(currentShape)).setBoundBoxWidth(shapeWidth + (moveEndX - moveStartX));
                        ((BoundRectShapes)(currentShape)).setBoundBoxHeight(shapeHeight + (moveEndY - moveStartY));
                    }
                }
                // tell the applet to redraw the shapes
                ntcModel.repaint();

           break; // break for case Action = 1 (Move)

           case RESIZE: // case for case Action = 2 (Resize)

              // This is the code transplanted from GUIDemo
               /* Concept - click the mouse somewhere in a shape and drag to change it's size. I need to
                * Capture the Mouse pressed event when the resize box is selected
                * Capture the mouse dragged end location when the resize box is selected
                * replace the width and height coordinates (xSize and ySize) by adding (or subtracting) the difference
                * between the mousePressed event and the mouseDragged event
                * The solution will require logic that can handle all combinations of 3 x/y positions
                * 1) the Current starting x/y position of the object
                * 2) the Mouse pressed position (which can only be greater than 1) above
                * 3) the mouse dragged to position
                * In addition there are 2 scenarios:
                * 1) No shape present - nothing to Resize
                */
               // System.out.println("\n***Debug - The Resize Option is selected");
                if(currentShape == null)
                {
                    // Do nothing for now - later add a message to user "Remove What"
                    System.out.println("\nYou have asked to resize a shape but there are no shapes drawn");
                }
                else if (currentShape != null)
                {
                    // Look for dragpoint 
                    // If the shape is selected change it's Width and Height
                    // Get the current width and Height of the selected shape
                    int shapeXPosition = ((BoundRectShapes)(currentShape)).getBoundBoxWidth();
                    int shapeYPosition = ((BoundRectShapes)(currentShape)).getBoundBoxHeight();
                    // Get the ending x an y position after the drag
                    int resizeEndX = dragEvent.getX();
                    int resizeEndY = dragEvent.getY();
                    // Reset the selected shapes width and Height based on the difference between the 
                    // start (MousePressedEvent) and end (mouseDraggedEvent) of the drag
                    ((BoundRectShapes)(currentShape)).setBoundBoxWidth(shapeXPosition + (resizeEndX - resizeStartX)); 
                    ((BoundRectShapes)(currentShape)).setBoundBoxHeight(shapeYPosition + (resizeEndY - resizeStartY)); 

                }
                // tell the applet to redraw the shapes
                ntcModel.repaint();
           break; // break for case Action = 2 (Resize)
           case REMOVE: // case for case Action = 3 (Remove)
           break; // break for case Action = 3 (Remove)
           case CHANGE: // case for case Action = 4 (Change)
           break; // break for case Action = 4 (Change)
           default:
           break;

          } // end of switch statement
          dragInProgress = false; // Allow mouse pressed functionality to run again
    } // end mouseDragged method

    // I added this because I need to chain clicks for an abstract polygon "ArrayBasedShape" and to do
    // this I need the MouseEvent method getClickCount().
    // This is the MouseAdapter MousePressed Method - see if mouse is clicked
    //public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent releaseEvent)
    //{
     //   currentShape.getLineColor();
        // In order to implement fill I will have to test for each individual shape type
        //currentShape.getFillColor();
    //}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
((Shape)(currentShape)).setXorigin(shapeXPosition + (moveEndX - moveStartX)); 
((Shape)(currentShape)).setYorigin(shapeYPosition + (moveEndY - moveStartY));
```

to this:

```
((Shape)(currentShape)).setXorigin(shapeXPosition + (moveEndX - moveStartX)); 
((Shape)(currentShape)).setYorigin(shapeYPosition + (moveEndY - moveStartY)); 
moveStartX = moveEndX;
moveStartY = moveEndY;
```

So you don't multiply the movement. Similar for resize.

Comment: Yes, Thank you !! I have been staring at this for hours, I implemented your change and it fixed the problem.